# Update/Installs fails with unrecoverable dpkg fatal error because libc6-i386 is missing

Tags: 10.10, installation, 64-bit, dpkg, updates

I keep receiving this error every-time I try to do some updates.

I tried `sudo dpkg --configure`, `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install -f` but they failed on me.

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%  

 dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:

 failed to read on buffer copy for files list for package `libc6-i386': Is a directory
```

I tried to find the file but it appears to be missing.

`ls: cannot access /var/lib/dpkg/info/libc6-i386: No such file or directory`

And

`bash: /var/lib/dpkg/info/libc6-i386: No such file or directory`

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/info/libc6-i386*`?

Comment: how do i post it?

Comment: i mean how do i get it?

Comment: @JorgeCastro How do i obtain the output of that? Sorry still learning!

Comment: @Jonthue Run the command that arrange says in a terminal, then edit your question and add the result of that command there. That will give us information we'll need, thanks!

Comment: @JorgeCastro TY I just did.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at the following:

- https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/145648
- https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+question/131789

Unfortunately for you, both of them point to a corrupted disk ...

Comment: dose that mean i may have to buy anew hd?

Comment: It's impossible to tell, given the information you've provided. I would try fsck first as the links above suggested.

Comment: @JonthueMichel: quite likely you just need to run a disk check.