# Downloads stopping halfway in the Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: 11.10, software-center

```
Install Archives() failed: Selecting previously deselected package indicator-multiload.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 reading files list for package 'linux-headers-3.0.0-15': Input/output error
Error in function:
```

I'm new to Ubuntu, and I don't know where to go from here. This is preventing me from downloading anything. I've also had quite a few problems with Ubuntu in the last few days, I've done four installs.

It would seem whenever I update it, and I restart my laptop like prompted, it stays in infinite boot loop. Only solution is to re-install. At least that I've figured out. Thoughts?

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/30880/25798) might be relevant to you.

Comment: What are the other problems you refer to? Are they related to other things than updating and downloading?

Comment: @jokerdino Is the problem really the same there? `dpkg` reports a different reason for failing here than there. Anyway... This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that.

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal, run

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
```

Then,

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: I tried those before, but perhaps not in that order.

Still, it did nothing, it also said it updated nothing and such.

Ideas..?